Missing TTP header in rclone when copy files to AWS S3
I tried to use rclone to copy files from Alibaba Cloud OSS bucket to AWS S3 bucket. The command I used is
rclone copy -P ali-cloud:bucket001 aws-cloud:bucket001 

However, I got this error messages.
2024-05-06 06:41:47 ERROR : fileABC: Failed to copy: InvalidRequest: Content-MD5 OR x-amz-checksum- HTTP header is required for Put Object requests with Object Lock parameters
        status code: 400, request id: 0PXXXXXXXXXXRDE, host id: 

Any idea how to fix it?

Does your target bucket have Object Lock activated? This seems to give a bit of an explanation: S3 PutObject is missing a Content-MD5 header when writing to a bucket with a default object lock configuration · Issue #1694 · aws/aws-sdk-php

Thanks, John.  That's exactly what it is.
